# Unknown option when starting selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium

I am running into an issue.  When I try to kick off my selenium with parameters, it starts fine with 2.53.1 but complains about unknown options on 3.0.0.  I attached the full output below.  I looked around on the web and all I found was related to the -d paramters.  Suggesting that those come before the path to the jar.  But those are not the issue.  The parameters for Selenium are the ones complaining.  (But I did try reordering the parameters, to no success)

I am using 2.25 on my chrome driver.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but I am currently stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Gary

`
    **gmurry$ java -jar build-utils/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar --role=standalone  -port=6668 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=build-utils/selenium/chromedriver -timeout=3600 -browserTimeout=7200**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: --role=standalone
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:219)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:147)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:73)`
```

**gmurry$ java -jar build-utils/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar --role=standalone  -port=6668 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=build-utils/selenium/chromedriver -timeout=3600 -browserTimeout=7200**

    `10:49:49.560 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to build-utils/selenium/chromedriver
    10:49:49.632 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02
    10:49:49.633 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
    10:49:49.647 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
    10:49:49.751 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
    10:49:49.751 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
    10:49:49.752 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
    10:49:49.752 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
    10:49:49.756 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
    10:49:49.756 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
    10:49:49.854 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
    10:49:49.854 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running`

Comment: Place the `-D` switches before `-jar`. Also note your code is searching for the driver using a path relative to your execution directory. If you're in a *nix environment, use `~/...` to locate the driver. Otherwise you can just place them in your bin.

Comment: @neet_jn Thanks for the feedback, but I get the same results moving `-D` before the `-jar` .

Comment: Are you pointing to the correct drivers? Use an absolute path using your home directory. I also just realized `--role=standalone` should be `node`.

Likewise, do you have a hub setup?

Comment: This is my hub/node start script from my mac.

**hub**
`java -jar ./server.jar -role hub -port 4444 -maxSession 10`

**node**
`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar ./server.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444 -maxSession 10 -browser browserName=chrome,platform=MAC,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName=safari,platform=MAC,maxInstances=1`

Comment: @GaryM Can you try bumping up to latest Selenium 3.4.0, ChromeDriver 2.29 & Google Chrome 58.x? Next try once to play with the default configuration first. If things work well, next we can move towards your customized requirements.Thanks

Comment: @neet_jn Thanks a lot for your help.  None of those seemed to do the trick.  But I did find a solution that seemed to do it, I am not sure why though.  When we upgraded our JDK up to the latest version, things started working.  Thanks again for your help.